# after changing asp.net mvc3 connectionstring, asp.net configuration dont work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a problem with the asp.net MVC3.

when i create a new project and start the asp.net configuration my browser opens and i can edit e.g. the user.

but when i change the connection string to my external server or to my local sqlexpress server, i get the message after the browser pops up:

```
The type "MyApp.MvcApplication" could not be loaded.
```

what do i wrong? my connection string looks like:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="Data Source=my-pc\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Does it work when you change back? The error looks to me like something else is wrong - are you sure the compilation doesn't fail?

Comment: you were right, the problem was, that the project was not compiled before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the type hasn't actually been built and packaged as a DLL into the bin folder. Did you try running the project initially before making the change?